# What file holds the "Invalid username" message?

Tags: login, security, language

In trying to prevent username enumeration, I'm editing login messages to obfuscate whether the username or password was incorrect. I've successfully edited the messages for when the password is wrong, but I cannot track down where the "Invalid username" message pictured below is stored.

[image: "Invalid username" message]

I've edited `myaccount_lang.php`, but it's had no effect on this output. I've searched for "Invalid username" on my `/system/` folder, and updated the message anywhere I've seen it, but to no success. (The only other file I found it in was `moblog_lang.php`, just to be clear.)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in system/expressionengine/language/english/login_lang.php

Comment: Unfortunately, not the right file. It contains `'credential_missmatch' =>
'Invalid username or password.'` (which is great), but that's not what is displayed after the attempt. Womp womp.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hacking the core or using speciality templates, use [Custom System Messages](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages). It's great and super easy to use